# How to combine slideDown/slideUp animations with other properties using Velocity.js

Tags: jquery, velocity.js

I'm using Velocity.js to animate different things on my site.

I'm able to set slideDown/slideUp animation to my elements, but I would like to combine it with scale animation.

Example:

```
$('#myelement').velocity({scale: 0});
$('#myelement').velocity('slideUp');
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/mEXWGb)

I don't really know how to connect this two animations to begin 
simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found `queue` option in **[Velocity.js documentation](http://velocityjs.org/#queue)**.

> You can set queue to false to force a new animation call to immediately run in parallel with any currenty-active animations.

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
  $('#myelement').velocity({
    scale: 0
  }, {
    queue: false
  });
  $('#myelement').velocity('slideUp');
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/oLEPZP)

Comment: explain what you did and why